# TypeScript Unsafe Member Access when calling method from a Lerna Module

Tags: typescript, eslint, lint, lerna, typescript-eslint

unsafe member access when calling methods from a module (handled using **lerna**)

I have a project where a module is created using different typescript components.

**Example:**

```
export const localization: {
    formattedDate: (language: string) => string
}  = (() => {
  
  const formattedDate = (language: string): string => {
    //definition of the method
  }
  
  return {
    formattedDate;
  }

}
```

This file is part of a package, which is then **installed** in my **second project** and also added in the dependencies of `package.json`.

In my second project, I have imported **localization** and using its method **formattedDate**.

**Example:**

```
import { localization } from '@module/firstproject';

const output = localization.formattedDate("language");
```

This throws the below lint errors:

```
Unsafe member access .formattedDate on an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access

Unsafe assignment of an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

**Even though it is working fine technically. But typescript throws `no-unsafe-member-access` lint issue. I do not want to disable this and fix this issue.**

I have tried multiple fixes provided online. But, I do not seem to find anything wrong with the code. Even in the module's component, I have defined a proper return type of the method.

Comment: do you have a builder for your @module for transforming your typescript to javascript?

Comment: @Oro yes all that is in place.. my app is working fine. Just trying to figure out the lint issue

Comment: have you tried to create an index.d.ts file with declaring types for your module?

Comment: @Oro Yes, I have a .dts file declaring the component along with its type.
Example:

export declare const localization: {
    formattedDate: (language: string) => string
};